# email retrieved from userProfile is null (spring social)

Tags: spring, spring-social

Why sometimes my app retrieve from UserProfile email as null ? I use Spring Social and my configuration is the same like configuration in spring_social_samples project created by Craig Walls

```
Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);      
    if (connection != null) {
        UserProfile up = connection.fetchUserProfile();  
               }
```

and up.getEmail() is always null except  when I using my email from facebook developer account.

thanks for any help

Comment: Are you requested an access to user email during authorization for all these cases?

Comment: ok, I found solution : must only add <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email" /> to the post....

Answer (score 1):

This is how I created my button and worked fine:

```
   <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/facebook?scope=email"><button class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i> | <spring:message code="label.facebook.sign.in.button"/></button></a>
```